# Python: Using sum() on a list of ints

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a simple python script that takes a number, converts it to binary, and returns the sum of the binary digits. Here is what I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def sum2(n):
    a = str(bin(n))
    b = a.replace('0b', '')
    return sum([map(int, x) for x in b])

n = int(raw_input("Input number>"))
print sum2(n)
```

In plain English I take *n* and convert it to binary, and then convert it to a string. I chop off the *0b* (from *bin()*) and convert the binary characters into a list of ints and then attempt to *sum()* them.

When trying to figure out how to add the digits together I googled around and found that I should be able to *sum()* a list of ints. When I attempt to do this, I end up with this traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\scripts\sum2n1.py", line 9, in <module>
    print sum2(x)
  File "D:\scripts\sum2n1.py", line 6, in sum2
    return sum([map(int, x) for x in b])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

So I find out *sum()* needs an "iterable" to do it's job. I google around and find there's an iter() function I can call, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
There's also __iter__() which doesn't work either.
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm still quite a bit of a beginner. Thanks in advance.

(And no, it's not my homework.)

Comment: Even though it's not really what you're trying to do, you can sum a list of lists (to produce a list) like this: `sum([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [])`

Comment: Cute trick for this particular case, although obviously less general: `bin(n).count('1')`

Comment: that is a good trick for this case... then he doesnt need to even get rid of the 0b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are combining list comprehensions with the `map` function, in an apparent attempt to do the same thing twice. You want either:

```
sum(int(x) for x in b)
```

or

```
sum(map(int, b))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing wrong. Although (as evidenced by the rest of the comment thread) there are far far better ways of performing the task I set out to. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 6):

Why not simply

```
def sum2(n):
    return sum(x=='1' for x in bin(n))
```

or even more simply

```
def sum2(n):
    return bin(n).count('1')
```

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
def sum2(n):
    idx = 3 if n < 0 else 2 # adjust index for slice based on neg/pos number
    a = bin(n)[idx:]        # doesn't assign the '0b' (or '-0b' for negatives)

    return sum(int(i) for i in a)  # convert chars into ints and sum
```

Note, using slice notation to eliminate the leading `'0b'` or `'-0b'` is preferable to using `replace()`.

You can use list comprehension, or a generator expression for this.

**Update**:

In a helpful comment @DSM pointed out that negative numbers have `'-0b'` in front of the binary string, I updated the code to deal with this by adjusting the slice based on the sign of the number.

Comment: +1 since you beat me by a second with the same outcome for the function :)

Comment: `for i in list(a)` is redundant, you can `for i in a` instead.  (Think of `list(a)` as `[x for x in a]`.)

Comment: @DietrichEpp Right your are, not sure what I was thinking, sheesh .. thanks for catching that!

Comment: Two minor points: you don't need `str`, and this will choke on negative numbers, because they'll start with `"-0b"`.

Comment: @DSM Ah, yes, of course, `bin` produces a string already - I knew that .. I worked off the existing code. I hadn't considered (or dealt with) negative binary values before, I'll have to think about how to deal with that. Thanks for reminding me about the first point, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

try doing this instead on your return

```
return sum(map(int,b))
```

that should work

Answer (score 2):

By doing `[map(int, x) for x in b]`, you are doing the same thing twice.  `map(int, b)` would make each digit an int.  Or `[int(x) for x in b]` would do the same.  But you are doing both.  Pick one or the other.  Try:

```
sum([int(x) for x in b])
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't wrap the map call in the list comprehension.

Instead of

```
return sum([map(int, x) for x in b])
```

Do this:

```
return sum(map(int, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

One using reduce :

```
ans = reduce(lambda x,y:int(x)+int(y), L)
```